# Merge and minify javascript files by closure compiler in phpstorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, google-closure-compiler

I am using closure-compiler to minify and merge my javascript files in /js/app/* to /js/minified.js

I just found File Watchers in PhpStorm settings and want to do this automatically, but i am not familiar with the UI there. Can you please help me, what to change, so it will work as excepted?

Thanks.!

[PhpStorm UI for closure-compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BkKp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a full path to the Closure Compiler compiler.jar as a program
Other options depend on your preferences. Default setup should work out of the box, but you are free to modify the arguments/output paths in the way you like

Comment: Yes, but with this settings, it only minifies all files, but does not compile them in one, as requested. Path to closure compiler is right, works in terminal.

Comment: you need to modify the arguments to match the ones you pass to compiler when working in terminal

Comment: 'Path to closure compiler is right, works in terminal' - but won't work in file watchers. You need a full path there

Comment: Actually, it worked with this path. But i cannot make it merge files. It only minifies them.